# Why does my code print the whole string multiple times rather than 1 time?

Tags: c, pointers, command-line, input, command-line-arguments

I'm new to C.  I'm having some trouble understanding some fundamental materials in reading input and pointers.  I want to use a nextChar() function to read and print each character of a string that I enter in the command line.  I try typing "hello"..It displays "hello" 6 times.  Can someone tell me why this happens? How can I fix it? Thank you for your time!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
char nextChar(char* ptr)
{
    static int i = -1;
    char c;
    ++i;
    c = *(s+i);
    if ( c == '\0' )
        return '\0';
    else
        return c;
}

void display(char* ptr)
{
    assert(ptr != 0);

    do
    {
        printf("%s", ptr);

    } while (nextChar(ptr));
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char* ptr=argv[1];

    display(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c = *(s+i);` Where is `s` defined?

Comment: in regards to hanky panky's question, how can we debug your code if you don't post what you're actually running? Since the above can't compile, it can't be what's failing.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. There isn't a "s". It should be "ptr". I forgot to change the "s".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the nextchar function could be reduced:

```
char nextChar(char* ptr)
{
    static int i = 0;
    i++;
    return (*(ptr+i));
}
```

and display to

```
void display(char* ptr)
{
    assert(ptr != 0);
    char c = *ptr;

    do
    {
        printf("%c", c);

    } while (c = nextChar(ptr));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `%s` format specifier instructs `printf` to print an array of chars, until it finds a null terminator.  You should use `%c` instead if you want to print a single `char`.  If you do this, you'll also need to use the return value from `nextChar`.

Alternatively, more simply, you could change `display` to iterate over the characters in your string directly

```
void display(char* ptr)
{
    assert(ptr != 0);

    do
    {
        printf("%c", *ptr); // print a single char
        ptr++; // advance ptr by a single char

    } while (*ptr != '\0');
}
```

Or, equivalently but with less obvious pointer arithmetic

```
void display(char* ptr)
{
    int index = 0;
    assert(ptr != 0);

    do
    {
        printf("%c", ptr[index]);
        index++;

    } while (ptr[index] != '\0');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation is very helpful. Do you mind to clarify and give me smoe tips on how you mean by " If you do this, you'll also need to use the return value from nextChar."?

Comment: @user2203774 Basically what Mohamed suggested.  It'll work perfectly here but I think it makes a fairly simple function needlessly complicated.  And use of statics may not be a great habit to get into as it doesn't scale well if you build towards writing larger multi-threaded programs.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

char nextChar(const char* ptr){
    static int i = 0;
    char c;

    c = ptr[i++];
    if ( c == '\0' ){
        i = 0;
    }
    return c;
}

void display(const char* ptr){
    char c;
    assert(ptr != 0);

    while(c=nextChar(ptr)){
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    const char* ptr=argv[1];

    display(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```